Eating Cayenne Pepper while scaling Everest?
So, I don't climb. I have no interest in scaling Everest. However I have recently become enamored with stories about Everest and K2.
My question is this: has anyone tried including cayenne pepper in all of their meals while climbing Everest?
I know your digestion becomes hindered at high altitude, but cayenne and capsaicin aid in inflammation, pain management, aiding digestion, as well as promoting to alertness and warmth. To me it seems like a no brainer but I am just a nerd with a silly question.
I appreciate anyone who responds.

Never been to those altitudes myself (aside from in planes), but I think if you read the books from people like Chris Bonington who did relatively early (70s and 80s) siege style ascents, you mostly want foods that are easy to eat - making it harder by having capsaicin in there wouldn't fit. Turmeric might be a possibility.

There are many tools to try and manage inflammation and pain, as well as digestion. Perhaps cayenne pepper (or other peppers) might help some people. Some Nepalese dishes are spicy. But so are some dishes at low elevations.

Are you really asking if anyone has tried it, or are you asking if this folk remedy is really valid?

Never have tried cayenne pepper, but I can recommend chewing coca leaves from personal experience in the Andes.

@chicks --- If you're going to edit, please make the effort to do more improvements, rather than the bare minimum.
